# Roll a ball Combinatorics Question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, problem-solving

A trough has holes with diameter 1, 2, 3, ... , n along its base in that order. It is called an n-trough. The trough is mounted on legs so it is tilted with the smallest hole uppermost. With each n-trough there are n balls, each with integer diameter at most n. Two or more balls may have the same diameter. They are rolled down the trough one at a time, not necessarily in size order. If a ball drops through a hole, it triggers a trapdoor that closes the hole. A ball with diameter d is called a d hole.

A sequence of balls where all balls sink into a hole is called a sinkable sequence. For example, in a 3 trough the sequence 1, 2, 2 is sinkable. But 3, 1, 3 is not.

a) How many sinkable sequences for a 5-trough contain exactly one 4-ball and exactly one 5-ball?

I have worked my way through the different combinations ([1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,4,5], etc.) and wound up with 320 different sequences. Am I right? Could someone please help me check my working as my combinatorics is not the best....

Comment: We know 5 has to go in the hole at the end. And that means 4 has to go into the hole behind the 5-hole. That leaves three holes left to use. The only three balls we can have are 1, 2, and 3. How many of each ball can change, but there can only be 1 or no three. If there is a 3, there can only be 1 or no 2. And the 4-ball and 5-ball can be anywhere in the sequence.

I cannot post this as an answer because my combinatorics are not very good. Hopefully this helped.